# Background size cover does not work with CSS animation

Tags: css, animation

I tried to use CSS animation with background size cover ... but it seems that CSS animation override the "**background-size:cover**"

Visit jsfiddle.net/zNCY5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `background-size: cover;` in your `@keyframes`. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ex2mT/

```
@keyframes animation{   
    0%   {
        background:url(...) no-repeat top center fixed;
        background-size: cover;
    }
}
```

Repeat this for each percentage you have.

Comment: it works fine but do you know why it's not working on Firefox or "IE"

Comment: You have browser specific CSS, did you add the `background-size: cover;` to each browser's specific keyframes?

Comment: for the other browser you need to use multiple background and update background-position. switching background-image does not work nor in FF/moz nor in webkit but indeed in IE11 and Opera