# Multiple backgrounds, CSS3 Animations and background-size

Tags: css, animation

I am trying to build a page that uses multiple backgrounds and CSS animations to create a image slider in the background. In other words, I have one element with multiple backgrounds and then I use CSS3 animations to change the background position of each to produce an image slider effect, i.e. the images slide in one at a time, stay on screen for a while, then slide out whilst another slides in.

This seems to work fine, until I change the dimensions of the images using background-size to make the images fit to screen. Since my site is fully responsive and needs to work on multiple resolutions, this is a must.

I found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923557/background-size-cover-does-not-work-with-css-animation) that touches on the issue, but their fix does not seem to work for me.

Here is an example of my code (PS: I am using the canvas for other reasons, and am applying the background to it so I can draw on top of the background images. Don't know if it is maybe part of the problem):

HTML

```
<canvas id="bgCanvas" width="100%" height="100%"></canvas>
```

CSS

```
    #bgCanvas {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-size: cover;
        z-index: 1;
        position: fixed;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        -webkit-animation: bgSlider 16s linear infinite;
        background-image: url(/cards/be538ab8-972d-41c7-84d7-2abf0aa96e21/Images/cycling1.jpg),   
        url(/cards/be538ab8-972d-41c7-84d7-2abf0aa96e21/Images/running4.jpg), 
        url(/cards/be538ab8-972d-41c7-84d7-2abf0aa96e21/Images/running3.jpg), 
        url(/cards/be538ab8-972d-41c7-84d7-2abf0aa96e21/Images/running2.jpg);
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes bgSlider{
        0% { background-position: 0 0, 100% 0,  100% 0, 100% 0; }

        21% { background-position: 0 0, 100% 0,  100% 0, 100% 0; }
        25% { background-position: -100% 0, 0 0,  100% 0, 100% 0; }

        46% { background-position: -100% 0, 0 0,  100% 0, 100% 0; }
        50% { background-position: -100% 0, -100% 0,  0 0, 100% 0; }

        71% { background-position: -100% 0, -100% 0,  0 0, 100% 0; }
        75% { background-position: -100% 0, -100% 0,  -100% 0, 0 0; }

        96% { background-position: -100% 0, -100% 0,  -100% 0, 0 0; }
        100% { background-position: 0 0, -100% 0,  -100% 0, -100% 0; }
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.